# creating liferay plugin project in liferay 6.2 facing error

Tags: ant, liferay, ivy

i m trying to develop portlet in liferay 6.2 using LiferayPlugins Development Using ANT Tool and i m refering the below link for reference

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/11/liferay-plugins-development-with.html

But when creating portlet i m facing  error. please check the snapshot for error and if anyone has solution for this error please do reply.
and i also referred some solutions for this error in various forums but none of them working
[image: Error snapshot]

Answer (score 3):

The error messages tell you that ivy tries to download some dependencies from the internet. Either you're not connected while executing this build (it's typically only necessary on first resolution of those dependencies) or your network requires that you configure a proxy.

Which of the two it is, I'll leave to you.

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                       Thanks for your solution .                                                                   The problem is fixed and the error was due to not connected to the network so it was not able to download dependencies.